# Can i compile without life cycle method in EJB 2.0?

Tags: ejb

iam begineer in ejb's.I have one doubt in ejb 2.0,In session beans,i will create() with out args in EJBhome.But i didn't define any methods i.e., ejbcreate and ejbremove in the bean.So,Can i compile or run this code without those method in the bean?.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile it but cannot run it.  You must have a matching `ejbCreate()` method in your bean class.

If you are very new to EJB I recommend testing your code with [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/downloads.html) (here's a getting [started video](http://vimeo.com/6149008)).  Not because I work on the project (which I do), but because we aggressively check code for mistakes and will print clear errors as to what you might have done wrong.

The output can come in 3 levels of verbosity.  On the most verbose level, the output is more email response oriented and error messages include information like "put code like this -code-sample- in your bean."  The code samples even try to use your method names and parameter names where possible.

As well it is compiler style.  Meaning if you made the same mistake in 10 places, you will see all 10 in the first run and then have the opportunity to fix them all at once.  Rather than the traditional style of fix 1 issue, compile, test, get same error elsewhere in code, repeat N times.

And of course you can still deploy into another EJB container.  Sounds like you are stuck using a pretty old one if you have to use EJB 2.0.

Here's a [list of some of the mistakes that are checked](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-453)